# How does bis(glycinato) Nickle exhibit optical isomerism?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, stereochemistry

I'm a medical practitioner but sometimes I find time to discuss few topics of chemistry with my son who has just passed out his 12th standard exams. Regarding optical isomerism I have learned that a chiral center is an essential requirement as is there in "Lactic Acid" {CH4-CH(OH)-COOH}. But in co-ordinate compounds like "bis(glycinato)Nickle(II)" I find same ligand (glycinato) bound on either side of a tetrahedral Nickle with two atoms each of Oxygen & Nitrogen occupying the four corners of tetrahedron.
Then where is the chiral center?

Comment: The decisive factor is if the mirror image of the complex is or is not identical to original. E.g. meso-tartaric acid has 2 chiral centers that mutually cancel, the molecule has plane of symmetry and mirrored images are identical, so not optically active.

Comment: There are octahedral derivatives of this compound (and they can be chiral as all bis(bidentate-ligand) octahedral complexes are. If it really is tetrahedral, it won't be chiral.

Comment: This [question/answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141240/why-does-nigly2-show-optical-isomerism-despite-having-no-chiral-carbon) is somewhat related.